# AngularJS create a form directive with advanced validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hey I was wondering if we're able to create a directive in AngularJS that inherit from `form` element (with `$valid` properties) and where we are able to rewrite `ng-submit` behavior ?

You certainly ask why, because I need to check when user submit forms if he forgot some inputs in order to display feedback UI elements.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [Angular-validator](https://github.com/turinggroup/angular-validator) helps you
See [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/XbDYKrM2QUf8g1ubTHma?p=preview)

Comment: Just saw attribute ` required-message ` that will be able to solve my problem. I will test.

Comment: Good luck. And notice, the data does not pass until all required fields will be filled.

Comment: I check angular-validator but it's only one attribute that I need in order to do what I want so if it's possible I'd like to do it with a directive, it will be more efficient and it will make me work on directives, what I really need.

But anyway thanks for this if I'm not able to create my own I'll used that.

Comment: You can use pristine and dirty to check for form input. For more you can refer to this link [https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation)

Comment: Already check that link, it's useful for pre-submitting validation not for post-submitting.